# Handling multiple artifacts from single maven project

Tags: apache-flex, maven-2, flex4, maven-plugin

I have a maven project that produces many artifacts. Of course it is kind of against maven best practice (one pom one artifact), but it is Adobe Flex project that produces many *swf modules and it is really makes no sence to create a separate project for each module.

For me it would be very convinient to handle all swf modules as a single zip archive eg. zip archive would be my artifact.

So I am looking for the way to pack and unpack my zip artifact with maven.

If you have any ideas, please share then with me.

Best regards,
Max

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer: Maven Assembly Plugin
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/ and Maven Dependency Plugin http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/