# Different dependency scope for webapp and standalone java app

Tags: java, tomcat, maven

I'm using maven to build a Java web application which is run in Tomcat. Certain JAR files (e.g. mail-1.4.1.jar and database drivers) have been put in tomcat/lib directory and the maven dependency set to "provided". (I'm not 100% sure why, but I think it's something to do with JNDI.)

Now I have built a standalone executable Java program in the same Maven project which I am trying to execute using `mvn exec:java`. Unsurprisingly it can't find mail.jar and I get the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Session`

How do I specify javax.mail scope="runtime" for the standalone Java program whilst still being "provided" for the Tomcat app? Do I have to use Maven profiles? If so, where can I find useful documentation on how this works (are the profile's dependencies additive or do they overwrite the default ones etc?)

Comment: If you have two different intentions web app and execution of a java app you should have two different maven modules. One for the webapp and one for the command line app. Otherwise you will get in trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Raghuram answer is correct, but I want to point out something.

As Sonatype wrote it in its blog : http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/

> I want to be very clear about this answer.   We strongly recommend that you not configure a Maven project to create two separate JARs from a single project.  It violates one of the most important core concepts of Maven: modularity.

What you are doing doesn't seem to be in "The Maven Way". When you start to be stucked with such a problem, you should always think that this is maybe not the right solution you chose.

There is a lot of topic about this kind of issue, around dealing multiple artifacts with one single pom :

[Handling multiple artifacts from single maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915588/handling-multiple-artifacts-from-single-maven-project)

[Maven: Attaching multiple artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239627/maven-attaching-multiple-artifacts)

...

And there is a good one about how deal with multiple environnement profile, as Raghuram suggested :
[Maven best practice for generating artifacts for multiple environments [prod, test, dev] with CI/Hudson support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424118/maven-best-practice-for-generating-artifacts-for-multiple-environments-prod-te)

So, I advise you to split your project, thinking about the real realationship between them.
It may probably drive you to a multimodule project like

```
parent
|
+--project:jar
|
+--web-app:war
```

...

Take a look here : http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

You can read the [introduction to profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

The scope of the dependencies declared in the profile will override the default scope when the profile is active.  So you should be able to specify `<runtime>` scope for the relevant jars within your profile and have it available for your standable app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Raghuram suggests, creating a profile with a dependency with a different scope works.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>standalone</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Elsewhere the artifact is declared with provided scope, as needed by the web app.

Run using:

> mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=XXX -Pstandalone

But I'm not convinced that using profiles is the right answer.